# Is it possible for an Apple Watch app to interact with Apple TV?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tvos, watchos

I'm searching for a solution or even a clue about the possibility of sharing data, sending signal etc, between `Apple Watch` app and `Apple TV` app.
In my case, I have an app that makes some calculations using the `Apple Watch` and I want those calculations to have an influence on the `Apple TV` app interface.

If not - Can I achieve it? via:

> Apple Watch -> iPhone -> Apple TV?

Thanks

Ariel

Comment: What iPhone apps communicate with Apple TV except the remote app?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a way to directly communicate between Apple TV and Apple Watch, but you can definitely go from Apple Watch -> iPhone -> Apple TV and vice versa.

From Apple Watch to iPhone you can use WatchConnectivity.framework.
From iPhone to Apple TV you can use Bonjour network.

We are using Bonjour network, setup with [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket), in one of our apps and it works great.

Comment: Thanks, as you suggested i actually use WatchConnectivity at the moment to transfer data between Apple Watch and iPhone. I will give it a try and post back with my results. Meanwhile, if any other great ideas come up, feel free to throw them at me

Comment: What about CloudKit?