# Swift problem with URLSession in Watchkit XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, urlsession

I got a problem with UrlSession and a .local domain.

When I send a Request to the IP address of the device in my home network it works. But when I use the .local domain for example "http://esp8266.local" it don't work and there are some errors.
On the IOS App it works fine.

This doesn't work on Watchkit but on IPhone App it works fine:

> PDTask .<1> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataPDTask .<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataPDTask .<1>",
>       "LocalDataTask .<1>"
>   ), NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://esp8266.local/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://esp8266.local/}

```
  let url = URL(string: "http://esp8266.local")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        print(response!)
        if error != nil {
        print("FAIL")
        print(error!)
        } else {
            print("OKEY")
            print(data!)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
```

And this works fine:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.109")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        print(response!)
        if error != nil {
        print("FAIL")
        print(error!)
        } else {
            print("OKEY")
            print(data!)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: How would your watch know what IP address http://esp8266.local points to?. I know there are some routers that can map local devices to ip addresses based on their name, but if your watch isn't connecitng to the same router your device is, it wont be able to resolve the DNS.

Comment: Its connected all in the same network. And its called bonjour. Why does it work with the IPhone App and doesn't work with the Applewatch/Watchkit... ?

Comment: maybe you need to use something in WatchConnectivity.framework to get the phone to do the request? i was just looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039609/is-it-possible-for-an-apple-watch-app-to-interact-with-apple-tv

Comment: No its independent from the Iphone app. You can send a Http Request via watchkit the problem is that it doesn't work with the .local domain and my question is what I can do that it will work.

Comment: it looks like the watch isn't running the bonjour services, the bonjour related classes such as https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/netservice aren't showing as being available to WatchOS. If thats the case, automatic discovery wont work. Other options would be creating your own A record on a custom domain you own, configuring your router to route those requests, routing via the iPhone, or just using the IP. Good luck with it anyway, i can't provide a good answer on this one as I haven't looked into Bonjour that much